# Open dialog to register vehicle on the register of notes

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Personally I have a registration page of notes, it got a selectOneMenu vehicle. But I want to offer the user the ability to click a button to open a dialog where he registers a vehicle if you do not already in the registry. And this is set back in the notes page to close the dialog. I know it sounds very simple. But would an example of how I can do this.I use JSF, Primefaces, JEE7 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most important, the buttons:

In main page, surrounded by form `mainForm`:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" 
                 value="New" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.prepareCreate}" 
                 update=":formInDialog" 
                 oncomplete="PF('dialogWidgetVar').show()"/>
```

In `bean.prepareCreate` you create the new entity for binding into.

In dialog, which has its own form `formInDialog` inside it:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.create}" 
                 value="Save" 
                 update=":mainForm:listOfEntities, formInDialog, :growl" 
                 oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed {PF('dialogWidgetVar').hide()}" />
```

`formInDialog` and `growl` needs to be updated in case of errors.

Comment: I managed to open the register in another xhtml page with modal is saving properly after save and close this window. But my menu select one of the records of notes so when I give F5 refreshes the page as I do to refresh yourself?